# How to build task 'elasticsearch:import:model'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rake, rake-task

Well, I have elasticsearch-rails gem installed (version 0.1.5) and I can clearly see the task inside the gem files.

But when I run

```
bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Comment'
```

I get this error.

Running `rake environment -D` doesn't show me the task either.

elasticsearch is running, if I curl `http://localhost:9200` it responds me.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Just to confirm: you've got elasticsearch-rails in your Gemfile and have `bundle install`ed?

Comment: I do have it. But this thing is just too unstable to use. I managed to import my model manually, but now it returns 0 results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need create elasticsearch.rake

```
cat lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

Comment: yes, i figured that out eventually and forgot to update this. Thank you!