# Elasticsearch & Bonsai: IndexMissingException on Heroku, works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

Building my first rails app and having issues getting Elasticsearch to run on Heroku.

Local works perfect.

On Heroku I can open the search page, but when I try to perform a search I get the error below:

**Heroku logs show:**

```
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969673+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ([404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[homes] missing]","status":404}):
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969674+00:00 app[web.1]:      9: <% end %>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969676+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:  
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969677+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <ul>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969678+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:   <% @homes.each do |home| %>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969679+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <li>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969680+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:       <h3>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969682+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:         <%= link_to home.name, controller: "homes", action: "show", id: home._id%>
2015-05-18T12:05:15.969683+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/search/search.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_search_search_html_erb___1261310385184340853_69929402195100'
```

**Gems:**

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 0.0.4'
```

**Search Controller:**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def search
      if params[:q].nil?
        @homes = []
      else
        @homes = Home.search params[:q]
      end
    end 
end
```

**Search View:**

```
<h1>Homes Search</h1>

<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @homes.each do |home| %>
    <li>
      <h3>
        <%= link_to home.name, controller: "homes", action: "show", id: home._id%>
      </h3>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you also show your logs from the ES server?

Comment: @janfoeh - Not sure how to access the ES server logs, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Val that question is probably better directed at you, as I am not familiar with Elasticsearch :) But if I had to guess, I would start by logging into your Bonsai dashboard.

Comment: Are you sure you've properly set up your `homes` index and mapping type on your Heroku ES instance? What do you see when running `curl -XGET http://account.region.bonsai.io/homes/_search`, where `account` and `region` should be replaced with your own settings.

Comment: @Val - when I run that I get:

{"error":"IndexMissingException[[homes] missing]","status":404}

Comment: Then you just need to set up your `homes` index the same way you did on your local workstation since you said it was working fine locally. Does it make sense?

Comment: Hmmm, when I set it up locally it just worked, I didn't have to run through setting up the the index. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/)

Comment: I see. Have you been through the "Custom Mapping" part, too?

Comment: No, I haven't gone past the 'Enhance the search' part. Was trying to make sure the basics worked going further.

Comment: Looks a lot like [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/25#issuecomment-36337055), do you confirm?

Comment: @Val - that does sound like my issue. I ran the command `heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Home' FORCE=true` and got the error `Don't know how to build task 'elasticsearch:import:model'`  

@hirenbhalani thanks for chiming in - I'm new to this so unfortunately i'm not sure how to index the old records.

Comment: @LarryC Good, one step forward. Regarding your latest issue, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/26783808/4604579 and shouldn't it be `CLASS='Home'`?

Comment: @Val, you're right - i corrected the class. Created the file elasticsearch.rake and it contains `namespace :elasticsearch do
 require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
end` - unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try to create the index manually (`curl -XPOST http://account.region.bonsai.io/homes`) and see what unfolds?

Comment: @Val - you're the best. I ran that command, restarted Heroku and now it's working. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is similar to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/25#issuecomment-36337055).

The solution involves

1. running the tasks [highlighted here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-rails#rake-tasks)
2. making sure the [`elasticsearch.rake` exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26783808/4604579)
3. and finally if the 404 still happens to create the index manually using `curl -XPOST http://account.region.bonsai.io/homes`